# wordpress issues with WP REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am using WordPress with REST API when I am sending request or data from the WordPress site it is stored in the format

```
`a:3:{i:0;s:2:"BS";i:1;s:5:"Mphil";i:2;s:3:"Phd";`}
```

as I am sending just multi-select value which is

`["BS", "Mphil", "Phd"]`

and it saves in the database in the above format which I have mentioned early. I am using Ultimat member plugin the data I am sending is of that plugin.

I am troubling how to store such data through `WP REST` API.

thanks

Comment: https://wpengine.com/support/wordpress-serialized-data/

Comment: `var_dump(unserialize($varibale))` . https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: can you please tell me how it is done in WP REST API?

Comment: post your `endpoint` line of code here.

Comment: `var_dump(serialize(["BS", "Mphil", "Phd"]));` - looks familiar …?

Comment: how can we do it in Postman?

Comment: you need to do serialize your array before to push to database by api

Comment: How to serialize in postman?